# How to turn off SSL certificate verification for RedHat Kickstartfile downloading

Tags: linux, ssl, redhat, kickstart

I'm using [Foreman](http://theforeman.org) for RedHat 6.0 booting over ipxe (but that shouldn't matter ;)

The kernel parameters used for booting are:

```
kernel http://192.168.1.5/dist/rhel/6.0/os/x86_64/images/pxeboot/vmlinuz ks=https://puppet.at.internal/unattended/provision ksdevice=bootif network kssendmac
```

When anaconda tries to load the KS file it gives me this error:

> Error downloading https://puppet.at.internal/unattended/provision:
>   Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)

Unfortunately google is as helpful as the Redhat docs - there's no information on how to turn off SSL verification :(
Since I am using at.internal as domain I also cannot get an official certificate but, due to the company restrictions i must use https...

It would be also okay if it would be possible to add the CA (or certfile) as a bootcmd.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Use the anaconda option `noverifyssl` to disable SSL certificate checking

specifically in the DEFAULT file for pxebooting, in the APPEND section, list `inst.noverifyssl` before the initrd line. It should look like this:

```
APPEND inst.noverifyssl initrd=/<path to your kernel> ks=https://<path to your repo>
```

Comment: The question was about RedHat but maybe this is also helpful here: https://docs.centos.org/en-US/8-docs/advanced-install/assembly_kickstart-and-advanced-boot-options/

Answer (score 2):

After I stumbled about this, it seems that the configuration option to turn off ssl verification was renamed to

```
md.noverifyssl
```

See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/dracut.cmdline.7.html

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have found, testing with CentOS 7 and a kickstart file hosted on an improperly SSL cert-ed URL, `noverifyssl` cannot be specified where you were trying to, in the kernel line.

`noverifyssl` is an Anaconda flag, but Anaconda does not parse this command, initrd.img does.

I tried the following tests:

`..` will indicate this line as it remained the same in all tests

```
vmlinuz initrd=initrd.img inst.stage2=[auto-populated stage 2 path]
```

```
.. ks=https://my.badly.certd-url.com/dummy/url.ks noverifyssl
```

Result: curl error over insecure CA cert, ignored the flag

```
.. ks=https://my.badly.certd-url.com/dummy/url.ks --noverifyssl
```

Result: curl error over insecure CA cert, ignored the flag

```
.. ks="https://my.badly.certd-url.com/dummy/url.ks -k"
```

I tried this to see if i could pass the `-k` flag to curl, allowing an insecure connection.
Result: curl error, could not parse because of quotes

```
.. ks=https://my.badly.certd-url.com/dummy/url.ks\ -k
```

I tried this to see if i could pass the `-k` flag to curl, allowing an insecure connection.
Result: curl error over insecure CA cert, ignored the flag

After am error, when my install process dumped to dracut emergency shell i executed

```
> curl -k https://my.badly.certd-url.com/dummy/url.ks
```

and it returned my `.ks` file.

I solved this problem for myself by avoiding it entirely and rehosting my script on another server with proper certs. I used a github repo and pointed at the raw url for the `.ks` file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've CA certificates to allow SSL-based applications to check for the authenticity of SSL connections. They can be installed by:

```
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates openssl
```

If you have it, consider reinstalling it

Related:

- [cURL not working (Error #77) for SSL connections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55859036/55075)
- [curl: (77) pbm with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/269614/21471)

Answer (score 0):

Specifically in the DEFAULT file for pxebooting, in the APPEND section, list `inst.noverifyssl` before the initrd line. It should look like this:

```
APPEND inst.noverifyssl initrd=/<path to your kernel> ks=https://<path to your repo>
```